find ranked local extrema in kdb
I'm trying to find k: the local maxima and minima in a list a enlosed in the table t below. Further, I'd like to rank the minima and maxima based on a but only relative to other maxima and minima as below.
My approach for relMinMax, although correct and free of loops is verbose, and I suspect there's a far more terse and quicker approach other there. Thus, I'd like to know if there's a more efficient and/or idiomatic way to this in q?
a:1 0 2 2 3 2 1;
tm:2024.01.01+til count a;
t:([] time:tm; a:a);

relMinMax:{[t]
    t:update k:1 from t where ((a>prev a) and (a>next a)); // find relative maxima
    t:update k:neg[1] from t where ((a<prev a) and (a<next a)); // find relative minima
    t:update k:0 from t where i=first i; // ensure first row is not a maxima or minima
    t:update k:0^k from t;
    r:select from t where k<>0;
    r:update k:k*(1+rank a) from r;
    t:delete k from t;
    t:0!(`time xkey t) lj (`time xkey r);
    t:update k:0^k from t
 };
show r:relMinMax t;

time       a k 
---------------
2024.01.01 1 0 
2024.01.02 0 -1
2024.01.03 2 0 
2024.01.04 2 0 
2024.01.05 3 2 
2024.01.06 2 0 
2024.01.07 1 0 


This isn't as clean as I'd like but it's a one-liner version of yours
q)update k:{0^(update r:b*1+rank x from([]x;b:+[1*(x>p)&x>n;-1*(x<p:0W^prev x)&x<n:next x])where 0<>b)`r}a from t
time       a k
---------------
2024.01.01 1 0
2024.01.02 0 -1
2024.01.03 2 0
2024.01.04 2 0
2024.01.05 3 2
2024.01.06 2 0
2024.01.07 1 0

There is a cleaner way for sure....
